# Create a custom XML feed with Drupal 7

Tags: php, xml, drupal-7

I need to create a custom XML-feed in drupal 7. Is this possible with feeds?
If so, how to and... Where can i set the 'root node' of the XML?
Also, I'm adding fields to this XML but these fields need to be wrapped within other elements, how can i accomplish this? e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlns="..."xmlns:xsi="..."xsi:schemaLocation="..."> this is the 'root node' i need to add    
<calendar> these are elements to add around the field  
 <timestamps>    
  <timestamp>      
   <date>this is the date_field/date>    
  <.timestamp>  
 </timestamps>
</calendar>
```

So to resume: i only have the field 'date' and everything around (calendar, timestamps, timestamp) i need to add. This needs to be done for almost all fields needed.

The meaning of this all is to export XML customised according to a custom xml-standard. I haven't found a module capable to do this yet, so please advise.

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource. I used this in one of my projects.
Create a '**view**' then add '**page**'. Set format to '**XML data document**' then add fields and labels.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a Drupal 7 module for this...

There is [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) for Drupal 6, might be something there.

This may get you started if you want to build something custom:
http://drupal.org/node/276677

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and rather than searching for "xml", I figured any sort of node export format would work.  Then I found this: http://drupal.org/project/node_export

It claims to have the ability to customize the xml format

Answer (score -1):

This shows you how to import your xml file into drupal as nodes or content.

http://drupalwalla.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/use-feeds-module-to-import-xml-data-in.html